# Define a range based on the result of the INDEX function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, iwork-numbers

In Excel it is possible to write a function looking like that:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(...))
```

Where the end of the range of the data to sum is dynamically defined by the result of the `INDEX` function.

The same function in Numbers gives an invalid reference error (the `INDEX` function is working well by itself).

Is there another way in Numbers to define a range as a result of a function?

Comment: No, because `index` doesn't return a cell **address**. You'll need to use a modifier to return the address of your selection. Try using a `match` nested in an `address` rather than an `index`. I can't provide an answer with an example because you haven't described your data set.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `ADDRESS` was the way to go.

Comment: If you got it working, awesome! I'll transfer the comment to an answer just so it doesn't show 0 answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because `index` doesn't return a **cell address**. You'll need to use a modifier to return the address of your selection.

Try using a `match` nested in an `=address` rather than an index. I can't provide an answer with an example because you haven't described your data set.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,0,n))
```

Where *n* is the height of the columnar range to sum starting at `A1`. `OFFSET` is a volatile function, so avoid if that bothers you.

Comment: Offset would probably work in some cases, but with the `index` being used to look something up, it wouldn't be very efficient